# Is it possible to get access to files uploaded via FTP in the media module in Drupal 7

Tags: entities, media, files

I installed media module to select files from server instead of directly upload them but in the `library` tab only the `http` uploaded files are available not the FTP uploaded files. Is it possible to get access and select FTP uploaded files via `media` module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to get access and select FTP uploaded files via media module?

No.

When you upload the files yourself (via FTP or some other means that is not part of Drupal), they will not be recognised or known by the [Media](https://drupal.org/project/media) module.

There are a helper module called [Filefield Sources](https://drupal.org/project/filefield_sources) that let you add files downloaded with FTP to Drupal media management modules.  A variation called [IMCE Filefield](http://drupal.org/project/imce_filefield) currently integrates with the [IMCE](https://drupal.org/project/imce) module, but there is AFAIK *nothing* similar for the Media module.

It has [suggested](https://drupal.org/node/1139642) to integrate Filefield Sources with the Media module. However, there does not seem to be anybody working on it, (just a lot of people who want it).

If you *really* want this, you probably need to add this to the Filefield Sources yourself.

Comment: So the only way out is either upload them via `http` and let the content managers select them via library tab or use the your suggestion IMCE

Comment: AFAIK, yes.  (I'd love to be proven wrong!)